# closed table which splited into more than one page on each page

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

Hello I have add a table which extended on more than one page but i want close on each page can you help please declose table on the first page, second page if is extended on 3 pages and so this my code:

```
class InvoiceGenerator:
 def __init__(self, pdf_filename):
                    self.pdf_filename = pdf_filename
                    self.story = []
def generate_invoice(self):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(self.pdf_filename, pagesize=letter)

    # Add elements to the story
    self.add_header(doc)
    self.add_table(doc)


    def add_table(self, doc):
    COL_WIDTHS = [300, 80, 80, 80]
    # Example table data with random values
    table_data = [["Désignation", "Qte", "Prix Unitaire", "Montant HT"]]
    for _ in range(30):  # You can adjust the number of rows as needed
        designation = random.choice(['Product AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct AProduct A', 'Product B', 'Product C'])
        quantities = random.randint(1, 10)
        unit_price = random.randint(1, 10)
        total_price = quantities * unit_price
        # to return to line if designation is long
        tbl_row = [Paragraph(str(cell), getSampleStyleSheet()['BodyText']) if isinstance(cell, str) else cell
                   for cell in [designation, quantities, unit_price, total_price]]
        table_data.append(tbl_row)


    # Create the table
    table = LongTable(table_data, colWidths=COL_WIDTHS, repeatRows=1, splitByRow=1)
    table.setStyle(TableStyle([
        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
        # Grid lines for the header and columns
        ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1, colors.black),
        ('GRID', (1, 0), (0, -1), 1, colors.black),
        ('GRID', (2, 0), (0, -1), 1, colors.black),
        ('GRID', (3, 0), (0, -1), 1, colors.black),
        ("FONTNAME", (0, 0), (-1, 0), "Times-Italic"),
        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.darkgray),
        ('ALIGN', (1, 1), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
        ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (1, 0), 0),
        ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (1, 0), 0),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (1, 0), 'TOP'),
        ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (1, 0), 'CENTRE'),
        # DataTable
        ('ALIGN', (0, 1), (1, -1), 'CENTRE'),
        ('SIZE', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 7),
        ('LEADING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 8.4),
        ('VALIGN', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
        ('TOPPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 2.6),
        ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 2.6)
        # ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1),
        # ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1),
        # ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
        # ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),

    ]))
    spacer = Spacer(1, 40)

    # Add the table to the story
    self.story.extend([table, spacer])
 @staticmethod
    def table_style():
        tab_styl = TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
                               ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
                               ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 10),
                               ("FONT", (0, 0), (0, -1), "Helvetica-Bold"),
                               ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, -1), (1, 1, 1))])
        return tab_styl


# Example usage
pdf_filename = "invoice_example.pdf"
invoice_generator = InvoiceGenerator(pdf_filename)
invoice_generator.generate_invoice()
```

the result of my pdf is as shown in image i want just in the first page close table with using grid style to make a grid table : [image]